# ListView with custom layout for hidden fields?

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I have a listview bound to an adapter (in a DialogFragment):

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                  null,
                                  new String[] { "_id", "name" },
                                  new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
                                  0);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I would like to show only the name, but still keep the id, because when the user selects an item, the id is returned to the calling activity.

Would I need to have a custom layout with a hidden TextView or is there a better way to get the id from the current item?

Comment: I would use customer adapter for that. And in the layout, hide the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok You may go with Custom adapter.
But if you don't want to do it.
You can change the default behavior of your code by Overriding a **bindView**().

```
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(NavDrawer.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    null,
                    new String[] { "_id", "name" },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1},
                    0){
                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setText(name);
                    //here you can store your id on textview tag
                    tv.setTag(_id);
                }
            };
```

for getting the id

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        String _id = tv.getTag().toString();        
     }
});
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to avoid calling findViewById in bindView to improve performance?

Comment: Unfortunately.. I don't know yet. But you can reduce the call by making condition like if (view==null) as we do in listview ...And if you found better way let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this layout for your `SimpleCursorAdapter` :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Name it as `custom_layout` then change your `SimpleCursorAdapter` as follows:

```
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                                  R.layout.custom_layout,
                                  null,
                                  new String[] { "_id", "name" },
                                  new int[] { R.id.txt_id, R.id.txt_name},
                                  0);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `txt_id` `TextView` will be hidden and only the `txt_name` will be visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead creating again a wheel, you could use CursorAdapter.
Below example how to use it in fragment (I'm using getActivity() to get context).

```
//test: generating elements
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    values.add("word" + values.size());
}

//test: adding elements to cursor
MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "name"});
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    mc.addRow(new Object[]{i, values.get(i)});
}


listView = (ListView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new CursorAdapter(getActivity(), mc, false) {

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        //just example how to get _id
        Log.d("xxx", "it's id is " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    }

};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("xxx", "clicked id:" + id);
    }
});

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply , just donot set text for the item that you donot want to show.. hope this works..

thanks